# Automatically import image from relative path in Vuetify3's v-img component

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to display an image using Vuetify3's `v-img` component. The component works correctly if I pass it an absolute path or a complete url. The problem occurs when I try to use a local image using a relative path.

If I use the `img` tag directly it works.

**This works:**

```html
<v-img src="https://some-route/my-remote-image.jpg"> </v-img>
```

**This also works:**

```html
<img src="@/images/my-local-img.jpg" />
```

**This doesn't:**

```html
<v-img src="@/images/my-local-img.jpg"> </v-img>
```

How do I get the third example to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing assets automatically from tag attributes is done through Vite Plugin Vue (see [documentation](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/blob/main/packages/plugin-vue/README.md#asset-url-handling)). It can be configured through the `template.transformAssetUrls` config parameter, which you can pass an object with tag names as keys and a list of attribute names as values.

The Vite Plugin Vuetify has a pre-configured configuration that you can set directly(see [documentation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/master/packages/vite-plugin#image-loading)):

```
// vite.config.js
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue({ 
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    vuetify(),
  ],
}
```

---

Or you can add `v-img`'s `scr` prop manually to the plugin config in `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          tags: {
            'v-img': ['src']  //<----- add v-img
            // default values will be overridden if not repeated:
            video: ["src", "poster"],
            source: ["src"],
            img: ["src"],
            image: ["xlink:href", "href"],
            use: ["xlink:href", "href"],
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    ...
```